# Use .env file variables during Docker build

Tags: docker, environment-variables, sphinx

I am trying to use the sed command to replace variables during docker build. The variable I am attempting to do (to start) is $DATABASE_HOST.  The value for that is coming from my .env file.  I am reading online that environment variables are only available during run time if they come from the .env file.  Due to this, my sed command is not registering.

Dockerfile:

```
# Dockerfile for Sphinx SE
# https://hub.docker.com/_/alpine/
FROM alpine:3.12

# https://sphinxsearch.com/blog/
ENV SPHINX_VERSION 3.4.1-efbcc65

# Install dependencies
RUN apk add --no-cache mariadb-connector-c-dev \
    postgresql-dev \
    wget \
    sed

# set up and expose directories
RUN mkdir -pv /opt/sphinx/log /opt/sphinx/index
VOLUME /opt/sphinx/index

# http://sphinxsearch.com/downloads/sphinx-3.3.1-b72d67b-linux-amd64-musl.tar.gz
RUN wget http://sphinxsearch.com/files/sphinx-${SPHINX_VERSION}-linux-amd64-musl.tar.gz -O /tmp/sphinxsearch.tar.gz \
    && cd /opt/sphinx && tar -xf /tmp/sphinxsearch.tar.gz \
    && rm /tmp/sphinxsearch.tar.gz

# point to sphinx binaries
ENV PATH "${PATH}:/opt/sphinx/sphinx-3.4.1/bin"
RUN indexer -v

# redirect logs to stdout
RUN ln -sv /dev/stdout /opt/sphinx/log/query.log \
        && ln -sv /dev/stdout /opt/sphinx/log/searchd.log

# expose TCP port
EXPOSE 36307
EXPOSE 9306

# Copy base sphinx.conf file to container
VOLUME /opt/sphinx/conf
COPY ./sphinx.conf /opt/sphinx/conf/sphinx.conf

# Copy all docker sphinx.conf files
COPY ./configs/web-finder/docker/ /opt/sphinx/conf/

#  look for and replace
RUN sed -i "s+DATABASE_HOST+${DATABASE_HOST}+g" /opt/sphinx/conf/sphinx.conf

# Concat the sphinx.conf files for all apps
# RUN cat /tmp/myconfig.append >> /etc/portage/make.conf  && rm -f /tmp/myconfig.append

CMD indexer --all --config /opt/sphinx/conf/sphinx.conf \
    && searchd --nodetach --config /opt/sphinx/conf/sphinx.conf
```

.env file:

```
DATABASE_HOST=someport
DATABASE_USERNAME=someusername
DATABASE_PASSWORD=somepassword
DATABASE_SCHEMA=someschema
DATABASE_PORT=3306
SPHINX_PORT=36307
```

sphinx.conf:

```
searchd
{
  listen            = 127.0.0.1:$SPHINX_PORT
  log               = /opt/sphinx/searchd.log
  query_log         = /opt/sphinx/query.log
  read_timeout      = 5
  max_children      = 30
  pid_file          = /opt/sphinx/searchd.pid
  seamless_rotate   = 1
  preopen_indexes   = 1
  unlink_old        = 1
  binlog_path       = /opt/sphinx/
}
```

Comment: What you have read is correct; you cannot set environment variables (from outside your Dockerfile) during the build process. They can only be set at runtime. You would typically perform this sort of customization during container startup for example via an `ENTRYPOINT` script. This makes your image much more flexible because you can configure it without having to rebuild it every time.

Comment: Your `sed` command also isn't registering because you're trying to run it on a file in a `VOLUME` directory.  The single most visible effect of `VOLUME` is to prevent later `RUN` commands from modifying that directory; it does not "expose a directory" in any meaningful sense, and you do not need it to later inject a configuration file with a `docker run -v` option.  Does deleting the `VOLUME` lines help you at all?  (Note that @larsks is right and this shouldn't be a build-time option)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With sphinx the 'sphinx.conf' file can be 'executable'. Ie it can actully be a 'shell script' (or PHP, perl etc!)

Assuming your .env file makes real (runtime!) environment variables within the container (not overly familiar with Docker), then your `sphinx.conf` file could be ...

```
#!/bin/sh
set -eu
cat <<EOF
searchd
{
  listen            = 127.0.0.1:$SPHINX_PORT
  log               = /opt/sphinx/searchd.log
  query_log         = /opt/sphinx/query.log
  read_timeout      = 5
  max_children      = 30
  pid_file          = /opt/sphinx/searchd.pid
  seamless_rotate   = 1
  preopen_indexes   = 1
  unlink_old        = 1
  binlog_path       = /opt/sphinx/
}
EOF
```

And because it a shell script, the variables will automatically be expanded :)

Need it executable too!

```
RUN chmod a+x /opt/sphinx/conf/sphinx.conf
```

Then dont need the sed command in Dockerfile at all!